# Which Stack Exchange site can be used to ask questions about gaming?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about gaming like - can this game works in this pc, or how can I use this thing in this game, or such type of thing?

Comment: Perhaps http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ ***BUT*** check their posting guidelines first.

Comment: The first example you give would be closed as off-topic, the second might be acceptable.

Comment: If you're trying to decide if a certain PC will run a certain game, there's no better place to look than the system requirements for the game. Compare those to the PC you want to use. Asking it on Arqade (the gaming site) wouldn't get you the information any easier than that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your notification banner - you can drop down the Stack Exchange icon and search for other SE sites using the search tool:

[image]

Comment: +1 for not using beautiful red square and using free hand drawing instead.

Comment: @MarounMaroun +1 for realizing this detail :)